# How to create a Kubernetes deployment using the Node.js SDK

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I am working on building a project using Node.js which will require me to have an application that can deploy to Kubernetes. The service I am working on will take some Kubernetes manifests, add some ENV variables into them, and then would deploy those resources.

I have some code that can create and destroy a namespace for me using the SDK and `createNamespace` and `deleteNamespace`. This part works how I want it to, ie without needing a Kubernetes YAML file. I would like to use the SDK for creating a deployment as well however I can't seem to get it to work. I found a code example of `createNamespacedDeployment` however using version `0.13.2` of the SDK I am unable to get that working. I get this error message when I run the example code I found.

```
k8sApi.createNamespacedDeployment is not a function
```

I have tried to check over the git repo for the SDK though it is massive and I've yet to find anything in it that would allow me to define a deployment in my Node.js code, closest I have found is a pod deployment however that won't work for me, I need a deployment.

How can I create a deployment via Node.js and have it apply to my Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 2):

Management of deployments is handled by the [AppsV1Api](https://kubernetes-client.github.io/javascript/classes/appsv1api.appsv1api-1.html) class:

```
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();

const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);
const appsApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.AppsV1Api);

const deploymentYamlString = fs.readFileSync('./deployment.yaml', { encoding: 'utf8'});
const deployment = k8s.loadYaml(deploymentYamlString);
const res = await appsApi.createNamespacedDeployment('default', deployment);
```

Generally, you can find the relevant API class for managing a Kubernetes object by its apiVersion, eg: Deployment -> `apiVersion: apps/v1` -> `AppsV1Api`, CronJob -> `apiVersion: batch/v1` -> `BatchV1Api`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@c6o/kubelcient` kubernetes client. It's a little simpler:

```
import { Cluster } from '@c6o/kubeclient'

const cluster = new Cluster({}) // Assumes process.env.KUBECONFIG is set
const result = await cluster.upsert({kind: 'Deployment', apiVersion.. })
if (result.error) ...
```

You can also it using the fluent API if you have multiple steps:

```
           await cluster
            .begin(`Provision Apps`)
                .upsertFile('../../k8s/marina.yaml', options)
                .upsertFile('../../k8s/store.yaml', options)
                .upsertFile('../../k8s/harbourmaster.yaml', options)
                .upsertFile('../../k8s/lifeboat.yaml', options)
                .upsertFile('../../k8s/navstation.yaml', options)
                .upsertFile('../../k8s/apps.yaml', options)
                .upsertFile('../../k8s/istio.yaml', options)
            .end()
```

We're working on the documentation but have lots of provisioners using this client here: https://github.com/c6o/provisioners